# Play route/Controller just for unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework

I have a method that takes a Play `Http.Context` and "does some stuff" with the session. I want to write a unit test for just that method. Specifically, I want to test that if a request comes in with certain headers my method works correctly. It seems like the easiest way to do that reliably is to create a `FakeApplication` and a `Controller` for my test. Then I'd use `Helpers.fakeRequest` to get a request and `Helpers.route` to route that request to my controller. The controller would call my method, set some variables, etc. and I could then assert success and such.

Seems like a splendid plan but I can't figure out how to add a route to my controller in the `FakeApplication`. Note that this controller isn't really part of my app - it's just something I want to use for this one test. So I want to define it and construct in just this one unit test; I don't want to add it to my `conf/routes` file.

Specifically, I want something like this:

```
// Maybe I can use GlobalSettings.onRouteRequest but the return type
// is play.api.mvc.Handler which seems inaccessible from Java
FakeApplication app = Helpers.fakeApplication(new MyGlobalSettings());
Http.Request request = Helpers.fakeRequest().withCookies(...).withBody(...);
Controller testContoller = new MyTestController();
// This doesn't exist, but I want something like this
app.addRoute("/foo", ctx -> testController.method(ctx));
running(app, () -> {
    Helpers.route("/foo");
    assertThat(testContoller.itWorked()).isTrue();
}
```

I'm running Play 2.2.3 and writing in Java, not Scala.

I do realize I can construct an `Http.Context` directly and pass that to my method. However, this isn't my preferred approach for a few reasons:

- The `Http.Context` constructor takes the plain text of the session variables. I want to test that things work correctly when the request contains the encrypted session cookie.
- The `Http.Context` constructor is poorly documented and seems a bit off. For example, you can pass an `Http.Request` to the constructor, but you also pass the cookie data and session data. So what happens to the cookie/session data on the request? Does it get merged with the other data passed? Ignored?
- The `Http.Context` constructor is difficult to use from Java as it requires a `play.api.mvc.RequestHeader`, which can't be constructed in Java, and a `play.mvc.Http.Request` which can't be "usefully" constructed from Java (you can construct one, but without cookies, headers, etc. and `FakeRequest` can't be converted to an `Http.Request`).
- It feels more "black box" to send in a request and ensure things work rather than try to figure out how this particular version of Play converts my request it an `Http.Context` (e.g manually constructing a context seems more likely to break with new versions of play).

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of Play! are you using?

Comment: I'm running Play 2.2.3 and writing in Java, not Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Play Tests in format

```
running(fakeApplication(), () -> {
  ...
});
```

Are good for testing a running play app without the HTTP layer. However in your case you're dependent on having a http context so I your options are to either add in the http layer...

```
running(testServer(3333), fakeApplication(), () -> {
   WSResponse wsResponse = WS.url("http://localhost:3333/foo").setHeader("fizz", "buzz").get().get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ....
  //assert some stuff
});
```

or maybe try using PowerMockito and mock out the HTTP.Context call. As you point out this is more brittle but will allow to pragmatically spin up a quick unit test. Something like

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @PrepareForTest({ Http.Context.class })
    @Test
    public void test() {
        mockStatic(Http.Context.class)
        mockStatic(Http.class)

        Http.Context mockContext = mock(Http.Context.class);
        Map<String, String> args new HashMap<>();
        args.put("a","b");
        mockContext.args = args;
        PowerMockito.when(Http.Context.current()).thenReturn(mockContext);

        ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest();
        cut.someMethod();
        //assertions

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the thoughtful reply. I think the first solution, using a test server, has the same issues as I describe in the question: namely that the controller exists only in the unit test and isn't in my `conf/routes` so, as far as I know, you can't get Play (via `FakeApplication` or `TestServer`) to route requests to it. The 2nd version works but has the drawbacks we've both noted. Do you know of any way to get Play to route requests to a `Controller` defined in a test?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Before
public void startPlay() {
    String conf = System.getProperty("config.file");
    if (conf == null) {
        System.setProperty("config.file", "../../conf/test.conf");
    }
    System.setProperty("play.http.router", "customer.Routes");
    super.startPlay();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how you add an additional test route without changing your `conf/routes` file. But MyTestController.java needs to be located at project/app instead of project/test.

```
// app/controllers/TestController.java
public static Result foo() {
   return ok();
}

// conf/test.routes
GET     /foo           controllers.TestController.foo

// test/controllers/TestTestController.java
@Before 
Configuration config = new Configuration(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/test.conf")).resolve());
Map<String, Object> configMap = config.asMap();
Map<String, Object> application = (Map<String, Object>) config.get("application");
application.put("router", "test.Routes");
configMap.put("application", application);
fakeApplication(configMap);

@Test
FakeRequest fakeRequest = Helpers.fakeRequest("GET", "/foo");
Result result = Helpers.route(fakeRequest);
assertThat(Helpers.status(result)).isEqualTo(200);
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.